# Encryption and Decompiling

Tags: java, encryption, decompiling

Im about to put my Android app on the marketplace. I recently encrypted all of my server/client communication. What i am wondering is if my data is encrypted using a specialized key, and if a person decompiles my code and extracts the key, then is it even worth encrypting the data in the first place? My communications ran a lot faster when the data wasn't encrypted. With the game being an action game, lag is going to be a huge "fun killer" and from experience i know it is frustrating. I know the encryption makes the app a lot safer, it makes it safer for the gamers and the server but it causes huge lag. Is the security worth the deduction in performance? Is even worth using encryption when your code can just be decompiled? I already use Android Proguard but if someone really wanted to decompile my code, they would take the time to sort through all of that garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it is safe to operate under these assumptions.

- Client cannot be trusted. Ever.
- Server is authoritative source of information.

Don't trust data that clients send you, make checks and validations against it (like if someone tries to 'teleport' from one map corner to another, by sending modified location).

Accept only data that's valid.

Ban cheaters.

Encryption is ok, but when it does not harm the game or gameplay (in your case it does).

Comment: how could i "verify" data that is sent from the client?

Comment: Depends on your game logic, of course. If it's, say, Modern Warfare 3, you could check that player's velocity is no more than X units/sec if he's on his feet and no more than Y units/sec if he drives a vehicle.

Comment: He's biggest problem is he is not "really" using encryption, but merely "obfuscating" things, key is right there in the code.

Comment: @daniel yeah, but, technically speaking, it can be a symmetric encryption (we don't know what it is for sure).

Comment: I use Crypto to do all my encrypting/decrypting

Comment: Its obviously symmetric( I don't know of anyone who uses asymetric keys other than to encrypt symmetric key's). That's exactly what he should do, encrypt a symmetric key in the code, then use the server to decrypt that key and change the key every session...

Comment: how could i "verify" data that is sent from the client? <--- use HMAC, no need to encrypt the data...

Answer (score 1):

You put the encryption key in the client code? Well that is worthless, encryption on the other hand is totally worth it, the problem is you chose the wrong way of doing it.

Comment: @john for starters take any encryption keys off the code. Look into doing some public key crypto, or diffie-helmen between clients, but NO 2 CLIENTS SHOULD HAVE THE SAME KEY

Comment: can you post some example code to show me how you would do this?

Comment: @john you downvoted the answer and you ask for code ?? I am ok if you think the answer is wrong and deserves a downvote, but then why would you ask for code ?

Comment: because i didn't down vote, i think it was a good start to an answer i just want more elaboration, if you elaborate ill up vote

Comment: I upvoted you for your effort and your info, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would have probably used authentication instead of encryption (hashing all the data you are sending so that you can verify it at the server end). This will work for ordinary game info, because there is not much need for confidentiality. Unless you are sending in private user info like name, age, credit card info etc., I suggest you use plain authentication which is much faster than encryption. You can go for really simple hash functions or if you think that your game really motivates people to tamper with it, then you can use military grade hash functions like SHA-256 or above. But no matter which hash scheme you use, it should be much less time/resource consuming than implementing a proper encryption scheme.